# Disable System.err 

Tags: java

Is there a way to set the stream System.err so everything written to it is ignored? (i.e. discarded not outputted)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    public void write(int b) {
    }
}));
```

Comment: I have found another way: System.err.close();

Comment: @elou Do you know how to restore the original System.err after you've closed it?

Comment: Hi @Noumenon, I have investigate the question and came to the same conclusion as here: [It is not possible to reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286893/281188). If you need to reopen, you should prefer to backup the stream with `PrintStream _err = System.err;` before overwriting with `System.setErr(..)`. After that it's possible to restore with  `System.setErr(_err)`. Regards, Éric.

Answer (score 18):

You can use System.setErr() to give it a PrintStream which doesn't do anything.

See @dogbane's example for the code.

Answer (score 5):

Just set Error to dommy implementation:

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
                // keep empty
            }
        }));
```

You need to have special permission to do that.

```
RuntimePermission("setIO")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the err Stream to `/dev/null`

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/dev/null");
PrintStream nullOut = new PrintStream(output);
System.setErr(nullOut);
```

Comment: this is *nix specific, though.

Comment: Note: On Windows, use "NUL:" instead of "/dev/null".

Comment: /dev/null doesn't exist in windows (you can use NUL on those though)

Comment: @rachet freak, If you have a directory called `dev` it soon will. ;) (`dev` is short for development on my PC)

Comment: FileOutputStream is an overkill for this, you can use common-io NullOutputStream()

Answer (score 0):

Using [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)'s [NullOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.html), just:

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new NullOutputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers aren't incorrect.
I think with the use of the `nullOutputStream()` Function from the `PrintStream` Class it gets easier to understand what is happenening with less overhead.

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(PrintStream.nullOutputStream()));
```

If you want to restore the original Error Stream later save it before overriding it:

```
PrintStream origStream = System.err;
System.setErr(new PrintStream(PrintStream.nullOutputStream()));

// Do your Sutff here which is printing to System.err

System.setErr(origStream);
```