# Why cant I just create another scanner object after using scanner.close()?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

After using the scanner.close() method, I cannot open another scanner. I have searched my question on google to only find people giving a solution for a workaround. I just want to understand why this is a problem in the first place. can anyone explain why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scan.close();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(scan.next());  //NoSuchElementException
    }

}
```

I understand that having multiple scanners open at once can result in an outOfMemoryError, so I thought why not have it as a singleton utility class that you can call methods from? This class would open and close a scanner with each use so that streams do not need to remain open.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Scanner> list = new LinkedList<>();
        while(true) {
            list.add(new Scanner(System.in)); //OutOfMemoryError
        }
    }
}
```

which comes back to the root of my question, If we can all understand why the scanner class works this way, perhaps we could come up with a solution?

Comment: You can, but you closed `System.in`, so you can't read anything from it. The real question is why close it at all? If you're going to need another one, why not keep using the same one?

Comment: I simply just want to for the sake of exploration. I already know how to use the same one. I'm just looking further into the Scanner class and how it works, and why I can't re-open System.in once it is closed.

Answer (score 8):

From [the documentation for `Scanner.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--):

> if its underlying readable also implements the [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface then the readable's `close` method will be invoked.

So when you close the scanner, it's also closing `System.in`, which means you can't later make a new scanner from it, since you can't reopen a stream once it's closed.

And you're only getting an `OutOfMemoryError` in your second example because you're trying to allocate an infinite number of scanners and preventing them from being garbage collected, not because scanners are particularly heavyweight.

Comment: I added the example for OutOfMemoryError to show that there could be a better efficiency by being able to open and close a scanner when needed rather than keep one open until the program finishes execution.

So what youre saying is that its not the scanner.close() method that is the problem, I am getting an NoSuchElementException because once System.In is closed I cannot reopen another System.in stream.

Comment: That makes no sense. And I'm saying that it IS the scanner.close() method that's the problem.

Comment: " it's also closing System.in, which means you can't later make a new scanner from it, since you can't reopen a stream once it's closed."  Why cant we open a new stream once it is closed?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts in guidance @Joseph Sible.
your answer has given me a new question and has put me on a search for more answers,
Ive found another source.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286690/in-java-is-it-possible-to-re-open-system-in-after-closing-it

Comment: @PanderIT You can't reopen a closed stream because there is no API for it.