# Kotlin Stream closed when using use clause in while loop

Tags: kotlin, try-with-resources

My code is simple.
When I execute Main function, I can enter number for only once.
If I enter second number, `IOException: Stream closed` occurs.
Can you explain why?

```
import java.io.*

fun main() {
    for (i in 0 until 5)
        val number = readLine().toInt()
}

fun readLine(): String {
    BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(System.`in`)).use { reader ->
        return reader.readLine()
    }
}
```

Comment: The error explains itself, the stream is closed. `use` calls `.close()` on the resources after the block end. So `System.in` is closed, which [cannot be reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286690/in-java-is-it-possible-to-re-open-system-in-after-closing-it)

Comment: I found BufferedReader's InputSream is null.
But when I call readLine(), won't InputStream be recreated?

If not, is there any way to reuse readLine function?